# nicescroll activates scroll after the page scroll completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollbar

I am having an aspx page. In that page I have applied nicescroll for a div to scroll vertically. But the nicescroll will scroll the div only after the page's native scroll completes in sony ericsson mobile android version 4.2. I want the div to scroll first followed by the page scroll.

Here is my div tag inside the aspx page.

```
      <div id="divexample">                                                    
          <div class="row-fluid white-bg">
               <div class="row-fluid"><b>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblcode" runat="server" Text="Using this card?" CssClass="modalLabel"></asp:Label></b>
               </div>
               <div class="row-fluid">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblcode2" runat="server" Text="Here are the instructions" CssClass="modalText modalLabeltext"></asp:Label>
                </div>
               <div class="row-fluid center">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image5" runat="server" ImageUrl="card.gif" />
               </div> 
          </div>                                                 
      </div>
```

The calling section inside the head tag is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(
               function () {
                  $("#divexample").niceScroll({ nativeparentscrolling: "false", touchbehavior: "true" });
               }
            );
    </script>
```

and my css is

```
 <style type="text/css">
         #divexample
        {
            overflow:auto;
            height: 300px;
        }
 </style>
```

Please help me to solve this. I am struggling with this issue for two long weeks. I found several alternate ways to solve this but I had solved nothing with this issue. I t will be great if someone has fixed is

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$("#divexample").bind("mousedown,touchstart",function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. since, I am working in another project I hadn't tried this. Today I have tried the above mentioned code. but I am not getting the scroll bar. previously atleast I got the scroll bar but now I don't get scrollbar. First I placed the only code which is given by you. But not getting work. Then I placed `$("#divexample").niceScroll({ nativeparentscrolling: "false", touchbehavior: "true" });$("#divexample").bind("mousedown,touchstart",function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});` Now also I didn't get it work. Is it correct?  Please help me get over this. Thanks.